# Is there a mistake in Zagier's "Hyperbolic manifolds and special values of Dedekind zeta-functions"?

Tags: number-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, quaternions, geodesic, zeta-functions

I am having troubles  with Don Zagier's "Hyperbolic manifolds and special values of Dedekind zeta-functions", available at [this link](https://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/zagier/files/doi/10.1007/BF01388964/fulltext.pdf), and I think there might be a mistake. In particular the problem is in the proof of Theorem 1 (§2).
In this proof we have a quaternion **division** algebra $B/K$ where $K$ is a number field with **just one complex place**. $B$ is ramified at all real places (i.e. $B\otimes_K \mathbb{R}\simeq \mathbb{H}$ for al real places) and $K_1$ is a quadratic field extension of $K$ such that $B$ splits on $K_1$ (i.e. $B\otimes_K K_1\simeq M(2,K_1)$).

At the beginning of the last paragraph of page 288 he says:
"Let, then, $\Delta\subset \mathcal{H}^3$ be a tetrahedron with vertices $P_i=(z_i,r_i)\in K_1\times (K_1\cap \mathbb{R})_+^*\subset \mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{R}_+^*$ $(i=0,1,2,3)$. The geodesic through $P_0$ and $P_1$, continued in the direction from $P_0$ to $P_1$, meets the ideal boundary $\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})=\mathbb{C}\cup\{\infty\}$ of $\mathcal{H}^3$ in a point of $\mathbb{P}^1(K_1)$ [...]".
Here $\mathcal{H}^3$ is the half-upper space model for the 3-dimensional hyperbolic space.

My question is: **why does the geodesic meets the boundary in $\mathbb{P}^1(K_1)=K_1\cup\{\infty\}$?**

I tried to do some obvious calculations and I considered a semicircle going from $P_0$ to $P_1$ and then to the boundary. The coordinates for the centre $C$ of the semicircle are
$$C=\left(z_0+(z_1-z_0)\cdot\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right],0\right).$$
The intersections of the geodesic with $\mathbb{C}\times\{0\}$ are
$$\left( z_0+(z_1-z_0)\cdot\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\right] \pm (z_1-z_0)\sqrt{\frac{r_0^2}{|z_1-z_0|^2}+\left(  \frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2},0  \right)=\\
\left( z_0+(z_1-z_0)\cdot\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{r_0^2}{|z_1-z_0|^2}+\left(  \frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2}  \right],0 \right).
$$

So, if Zagier is right, these two points should be in $K_1\times \{0\}$ and this means that
$$\left[\frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{r_0^2}{|z_1-z_0|^2}+\left(  \frac{r_1^2-r_0^2}{2|z_1-z_0|^2}+\frac{1}{2} \right)^2}  \right]\in K_1$$

but $K_1$ is not supposed to be closed under complex conjugation and, even if we make this hypothesis, how could we know that those numbers are in $K_1$?

For these reasons I think there is a lack in the proof (or a mistake!). Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: While I like your question in principle, it's impossible to understand your attempts without understanding what $K_1$ is. I can see, implicitly from your notation, that it is a subset of $\mathbb C$, but I have no idea of what kind of subset it is. Can you at least give *some* idea of what $K_1$ is? Please keep in mind our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post, where you will see this quote: *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question...*

Comment: @LeeMosher Ok, I'm sorry, I have been a bit lazy in writing down the question. Now it should be a bit better.

Comment: Okay, so, here's a few thoughts regarding a different method. Can one can assume that $P_0 = (0+0i,1)$? I.e. if one use the coordinates of the given $P_0=(x+iy,r)$ to write down an element of $A \in \text{SL}(K_1)$ such that $A(P_0)=(0+0i,1)$, and if one can solve that special case, then the general case follows.

Comment: And if that works then, assuming that $P_0 = (0+0i,1)$, can one also assume that $P_1$ has the form $P_1 = (0+0i,s)$? I.e. can one use the coordinates of the given $P_1$ to write down an element $B \in \text{SL}(K_1)$ that fixes $(0+0i,1)$ and that transforms $P_1$ to an element of the form $(0+0i,s)$? If so, you're done, because then the endpoints of the line through the two points $P_0=(0+0i,1)$ and $P_1=(0+0i,s)$ are $(0+0i,0)$ and $\infty$, and $A^{-1}B^{-1} \in \text{SL}(K_1)$ takes those two points to points of the desired form $(a+bi,0)$ with $a+bi \in K_1$.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not sure how much one needs to know about $K_1$ to make all these steps work; for all I know this could work for any subfield $K_1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ whatsoever.

Comment: @LeeMosher If $M=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d \end{pmatrix}\in SL(2,K_1)$ the action on $(z,r)$ should give $(z^*,r^*)$ with $$z^*=\frac{(az+b)(\overline{cz}+\overline{d})+a\overline{c}r^2}{|cz+d|^2+|c|^2r^2}$$ and $$r^*=\frac{r}{|cz+d|^2+|c|^2r^2}.$$ So we cannot even be sure that if we move a point with coordinates in $K_1\times (K_1\cap\mathbb{R})_+^*$ its image has the same kind of coordinates, because Zagier don't say if $K_1$ is closed under complex conjugation or not.

Comment: @LeeMosher Another thing: Zagier wants to prove you can choose $P_1$ vertical on $P_0$ using that the geodesic intersects the boundary in $K_1$, not the converse.

Comment: Crossposted at MO: https://mathoverflow.net/q/452744/6518

Comment: Let me also transfer my comment from there here, just in case. The question amounts to asking whether for $z_0,z_1\in K_1$ and $r_0,r_1\in K_1\cap\mathbb R$ there is a $q\in K_1$ with$$\bar z_0+\frac{r_0^2}{z_0+q}=\bar z_1+\frac{r_1^2}{z_1+q}$$